# Binding ng-click and input element angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have several input elements in a form. So when the user types in one of the input elements, the other inputs should disappear and some suggestions are provided to the user based on what they're typing (AJAX). If the user selects one of the suggestions, then the selected value will be stored into the database and now the hidden input elements should appear back. Up to this part  is doable. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to make the hidden inputs visible when the focused input element loses focus. Basically the code should reset everything (bring back the hidden elements and reset the suggestions) if the user leaves the input element without picking one of the provided suggestions. In a normal situation this can be achieved with ng-blur:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="lastName" 
                    ng-blur="lastName=''; focused=false; resetData();"
                    ng-focus='focused=true;'
                    ng-keyup = 'ajaxCall(lastName)'
                    ng-click=''
                    ng-change=''><br>
```

But this does not work in my case because before the user selects one of the suggestions the ajaxdata is reset by ng-blur. I was initially thinking that this is not challenging case but for some reason I cant figure out how to achieve this. Here is the code for what I've got so far:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OAiCgSIpb2dKLLWH0jfF?p=preview

Any comment is appreciated!

Comment: Click comes after Blur. So when you are clicking suggestion, blur event is fired first. Use Mousedown event with jquery i guess ..

Comment: That's exactly the reason but i could not find any solution for it